# Documenting PUT REST call without body and with path and query parameters

Tags: java, spring-restdocs

There's REST API call designed via HTTP PUT that has only path and query parameters and does not need a body:

```
PUT /posts/{id}/read?currentUser={loginId}
```

Trying to document it using Spring REST Docs 2.0.0.RELEASE I noticed that `http-request.adoc` is as below:

```
[source,http,options="nowrap"]
----
PUT /posts/42?currentUser=johndoe HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

currentUser=johndoe
----
```

I am confused, why `currentUser=johndoe` is rendered in body (like form parameter)? Is it a bug? Complete example of application below:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @PutMapping("{id}/read")
    public void markPostRead(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestParam("currentUser") String login) {
        System.out.println("User " + login + " has read post " + id);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation();
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
                .build();
    }
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
                RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.put("/posts/{id}/read?currentUser=johndoe", 42))
                .andDo(document("mark-as-read", pathParameters(
                        parameterWithName("id").description("ID of the Post")
                )))
                .andDo(document("mark-as-read", requestParameters(
                        parameterWithName("currentUser").description("Login ID of user")
                )));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you study [RFC 2616 with special attention on the PUT section](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) you will read…

> The PUT method requests that the **enclosed entity** be stored under the supplied Request-URI.

So the question is, although the spec is not 100 % clear in this part: Is it allowed to send a PUT request with no request body at all?

This is one of the questions on which you get 11 answers if you ask 10 developers but just to be fine with all imponderables, Spring REST Docs puts your query parameter in the request body just to be prepared for all those little more strict web servers out there. ;-)

Comment: Please refer to [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) instead of linking to the obsoleted HTTP specification further

Comment: The RFC is pretty specific by stating that you replace the current representation with the payload you've sent, which is empty. After processing the `PUT` request the resource should also not have any representation or a representation that expresses the same semantic (which can even be a HTTP 204 response). Of course the service is free to transform the received representation to a matching equal but different representation.

Comment: thanks for explanation @mle, I've tried to use PATCH method in this situation and Spring REST Docs documents it as expected (HTTP specification seem to be more reluctant as for existence of body in PATCH)

Answer (score 2):

Also, according to your endpoint "@PutMapping("{id}/read")", I noticed that in your REST documentation test the "/read" part of the path is missing.

Comment: Good observation.